# eliminar usuario si paso cierta cantidad de días sin entrar a la cuenta

Tags: php, pdo

hola una pregunta hay alguna forma para eliminar un usuario de la base de datos que no entro a la cuenta desde hace 1 mes?

esta es mi tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(2500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '08.jpg',
  `Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('user','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `Genero` enum('Hombre','Mujer') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Twitter` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rdate` date DEFAULT NULL, 
  `last_login` time DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `last_day_login` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

lo que tengo pensado es que cada vez que el usuario entre a su cuenta `last_day_login` se actualice con la fecha de ese día en concreto y si el usuario no entro a la cuenta desde hace 1 mes esta misma cuenta se eliminará

tienen idea de cómo hacer algo como esto?

Comment: Me parece tienes mla plnateada la estructura de dicha tabla, `users` es una entidad que va a almacenar la información relevante al usuario, pero no su actividad en tu plataforma, es decir la actividad de cuando fue la ultima vez que ingreso debería manejarse en una tabla por separado donde solo registres la fecha y hora así como el id de la tabla users, de modo que si la fecha del ultimo login es mayor o igual a 24 hrs transcurridas lo pongas como inactivo, de paso considero que a tu tabla users le hace falta una columna de status para que la eliminación sea lógica y no física

Comment: Lo anterior lo digo por que con la estructura de tabla que muestras ahorita me parece nunca vas a poder generar un histórico de los ingresos o logins del usuario en tu plataforma, ya que ese columna se va a estar actualizando constantemente

Comment: lo pensé pero la razón de no hacerlo asi es que quiero ahorrar espacio en el servidor y tengo más control desde la tabla ``user``

Comment: se espera mucho tráfico las primeras 24hs

Comment: Estoy con @Aprendiz. No creas que el hecho de tener una tabla menos te ahorra recursos en este caso pues es todo lo contrario. Una actualización constante de la tabla `users` es mucho más costosa en el caso que expones. Cuando actualizas una tabla podrían estarse actualizando los índices que se crearon sobre esa tabla, etc y eso, si la tabla tiene relaciones con más tablas del modelo de datos terminaría siento muy muy costoso. Además, meter esa lógica dentro de la tabla provoca un handicap importante en el sistema, si mañana te piden un informe sobre usuarios ...

Comment: ... que dejaron el sistema en el año `YYYY`, o que dejaron el sistema en el mes `MM` o que dejaron el sistema `X` meses después de haber ingresado... o usuarios de la ciudad `X` que dejaron el sistema, etc, etc, etc. Cualquier informe de esa naturaleza que te sea requerido va a ser muy muy complicado.

Comment: entiendo todo lo que me dicen, pero el problema es que actualmente la web la tengo hosteada en un host con muchos limites y esta cerrada al público ya que es para añadir contenido a las tablas, además si añado una nueva tabla como dicen voy a tener que re configurar casi media web, y lo de los informes no es necesario en el tipo de web que estoy creado ya que lo único que busco es eliminar un usuario y que no deje ningún rastro en la web

Comment: Lo más simple sería tener un cron job que puedes ejecutar una vez al día. En ese cron lanzas una consulta del tipo `DELETE FROM user WHERE last_login < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);` Esto se puede programar también en un evento de la base de datos, si el hosting te lo permite.